# Trouble with Flask and POST/GET

Tags: python, post, flask, get

So I have the following app.py file through which I am trying to process a post request which will essentially read firstname, lastname, username and password and then store it in mongodb but that is for later. As of now, I am having trouble receiving the post/get request.

Even the  small snippet that I am trying to run gives me a bad request error when I try to use postman to submit data to localhost:5000/register.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
from flask import *
#from pymongo import MongoClient
#import json
app = Flask(__name__)

# main interface
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

# Register Interface
@app.route('/register/', methods = ['GET'])
def register():
    #collection = db['userdb']
    firstname = request.form['firstname']
    lastname = request.form['lastname']
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    #postData = { 'firstname': firstname, 'lastname': lastname,'username':username,'password':password}
    #json = json.dumps(postData)
    #try:
        #status = db.userdb.insert_one(postData).insert_id
    #except:
        #status = 'This user is already registerd'
    return 'This data works'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you do need to add the "POST' method to the route decorator, but you need one more step. Use an if statement to make the view ignore the request.form assignments:

```
from flask import *
#from pymongo import MongoClient
#import json
app = Flask(__name__)

# main interface
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return 'go to <a href="/register/">register</a>'

# Register Interface
@app.route('/register/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def register():
    #collection = db['userdb']
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.form['firstname']
        lastname = request.form['lastname']
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        #postData = { 'firstname': firstname, 'lastname': lastname,'username':username,'password':password}


    return 'This data works'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is a common pattern in views that use both GET and POST. Also notice that I've added debug=True as an argument to app.run. This will make debugging your code a lot easier.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Really thanks a lot for the awesome answer. I am fairly new to python so did  not know that I had to do that. Thanks. :D

Answer (score 3):

```
@app.route('/register/', methods = ['GET'])
```

The above decorator means the handler will only be mapped to GET requests.

```
@app.route('/register/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
```

Try that and you should be good to go.

Comment: Oops, thanks T. Arboreus for catching that missing piece.